# "Payment Method" (in Contribute) vs. "Payment Processor" (in Events)

Tags: payment-processor, stripe

you've been very helpful before, so I'm hoping you can help again here.  I "inherited" a WordPress + CiviCRM site, and therefore I did not do the installation / configuration.  We are having an issue with the site now where the credit card processor both works properly and appears in a way that we like on our Contribute page, but when the same processor is called on an Event page, it looks bad / different, and it simply doesn't work.  The only difference I can see is that Administration for the Contribute page has a "Payment Methods" section in addition to the "Payment Processors" section, but the Events page ONLY has "Payment Processors."

[image: Civi Admin menu comparison]

In the Contribute page management area, I am able to select Payment METHODS, where Credit Card has been assigned to the Credit Card > Stripe payment processor, and we get this field which works brilliantly:

[image: Credit card payment interface via Payment Methods]

However, in the Events page management area, I can only select a Payment PROCESSOR, where Credit Card is obviously assigned to Stripe (as mentioned above).  That results in the display below, and trying to process any payment result in "Invalid request."

[image: Credit card payment interface via Payment Processor]

Can anyone point me in the right direction toward resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

Payment Processors and Payment Methods are both settings that apply to all contributions, no matter if they are associated with an event or not. If you click on those two Payment Processors links in the menu, they both go to the same page, i.e. it's just one setting, not two different ones. Payment Methods are associated with Payment Processors and also apply to all contributions.

For both event configuration and contribution page configurations, you can only select Payment Processors. If you select the same ones, you should get the same result on the event page or contribution page.

It looks like perhaps you have Paypal and Stripe enabled on your contribution page and just Stripe enabled on your event page, which is why you are getting the Stripe Link thing.

Comment: Even with both PayPal and Stripe enabled in the Event page, we get the green Link button instead of the credit card interface.  I'll keep digging - I can't understand why varying payment interfaces would appear when Contributions and Events are bussed to the same processing page.  Thanks for trying to help.